# Are Angular apps too big for phones?

Tags: angular, performance, filesize

I've built a web app and it's great on my desktop pc. However, people keep trying to access it on their phones, but it's very new and I didn't really make it for phones (yet). But... it doesn't even load on most phones at all.

I would expect it to at least load, but we just end up with a white screen. Could this be because Angular web apps are too big/intense for phones?

If so, how would it be recommended we handle people trying to access bulky Angular apps from their phones?

Comment: There are many mobile frameworks like Ionic available for use with Angular. The main key is the performance. Also the size of the application should be minimum as well. You can try to convert your Angular app to a PWA for mobile for better performance.

Comment: Oh, I actually have created a flutter app. But what do you do when people go to the site from a phone? Is there a way to detect they are coming from a phone, then redirect them to google play to download the app? And is that the appropriate way of handling that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In general, when doing nothing special, your Angular setup has a quite big footprint that needs to be downloaded and processed before anything else useful can be done and presented to the user.

This is why, in general you would split up your program into features / modules which can be **lazy-loaded** on-demand.  this would e.g. cause e.g a login page to be displayed after e.g 200ms instead of several seconds on a simple phone.

Besides this, there are other techniques like pre-fetching, offline storage, ... which will improve user experience.  I think, like with any mobile website, it need to be thought about from the beginning, adapted layout, adapted datasize) (1000+ datasets on a phone is most of the time useless, as where a desktop pc this would be ok (or more forgiving).

If you respect the browser support (https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)
 and your program itself doesn't have issues, there should be no problem to get at least something out of it.